# Creating instance of tomcat server from another machine on eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, raspberry-pi

I am developing a Embedded J2EE Application which I want to host on a Raspberry Pi board. I have finished developing the app on my linux laptop and to test it I am porting the app through sftp on to raspberry pi's tomcat webapps.

This becomes really tedious as for every error that I get, I need to recreate the War file, send it though ftp and start the server. As we can create server instances and run applications with ease on eclipse, I tried putting eclipse on the Raspberry Pi and use it through ssh, but it proved to be too heavy for the board to handle.

I have eclipse on my laptop. But there I could create only instances of tomcat that is present in the host machine(my laptop).

Is there any way that I can create an instance of raspberry pi's tomcat on my laptop's eclipse so that I can easily right click the project and say run as web application and it will actually deploy it on the raspberry pi's tomcat and run it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another method.

I suppose you create the war file with a build script (like Ant). Why not extend it to scp the file onto your Raspberry to the proper place, or even to create an ssh connection, start up the tomcat and `tail -f` the `catalina.out` directly to your Eclipse console. It's pretty easy to put together.